# Azure function app deploy and release pipeline error

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-functions, azureportal

I pushed my .net core function application using visual studio and now setting up release pipeline. I can publish and execute the application just fine and it works great on the Azure portal.  However when I see the builds for releases in azure-devOps that slot fails with the following error.

```
2019-06-19T23:21:33.3543380Z ##[error]Error: Deployment of msBuild generated package is not supported. Change package format or use Azure App Service Deploy task. D:\a\r1\a\_...AVFunctionCore.zip
```

I am not sure where I need to check in my setup to even start diagnosing the issue.

Here are the pipeline steps.
I create a new stage and then select a template of type (Azure app service deployment)

### Under tasks

App type is Function App on Windows

Give the app name, resource group , give the slot and
package folder as

```
 $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/AVFunctionCore.zip
```

Everything else on this is left as default.

Comment: Share the steps of your build and release pipelines, including parameter values. Also, did you follow the steps provided in the error message?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I am actual new to this.. " Change package format or use Azure App Service Deploy task." where can I do this? I tried looking for it in VS but couldnt find it and dont see that in devops either.

Comment: Please add the pipeline steps, what you are doing in Azure devops and add it in your question.

Comment: Hi Leo, sorry I didnt see these messages till now, working on the suggestions now..

Comment: To clarify, I did exactly the same thing. I'm using the deployment pipeline that is _automatically generated by VS_. So basically the automatically generatef pipeline doesn't function. That's not very useful

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Azure function app deploy and release pipeline error

According to the error message:

> Deployment of msBuild generated package is not supported. Change
>   package format or use Azure App Service Deploy task.

It seems you are not using the correct task to publish the generated package. Since the generated package is `.zip`, you can try the suggestion as error message said use Azure App Service Deploy task.

[**Azure App Service Deploy task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops):

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to deploy to a range of
>   App Services on Azure. The task works on cross-platform agents running
>   Windows, Linux, or Mac and uses several different underlying
>   deployment technologies.
>
> The task works for ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core, PHP, Java, Python, Go, and
>   Node.js based web applications.
>
> The task can be used to deploy to a range of Azure App Services such
>   as:
>
> - Web Apps on both Windows and Linux
> - Web Apps for Containers Function
> - Apps on both Windows and Linux
> - Function Apps for Containers
> - WebJobs
> - Apps configured under Azure App Service Environments

Check this blog [Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Azure Functions and Continuous Integration with VSTS](https://www.joshcarlisle.io/blog/2017/5/17/visual-studio-2017-tools-for-azure-functions-and-continuous-integration-with-vsts) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: says "not recommended" on the task

Answer (score 5):

I get predefined pipeline from VS integration. So for those you have the same case:

1. In GUI/Classic mode Release page -> edit pipeline
2. Edit task in stage section (this is responsible for deploying)
   [image]
3. Replace `Azure Web App` task with `Azure App Service deploy`
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I have more than one project (web api + azure function) in my solution. For the web app I used the zip file, but for the azure function to work I needed to publish the whole folder.

Azure Function
Package or folder:
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Backend/drop

Web Api
Package or folder:
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Backend/drop/ClientAPI.zip

Answer (score 0):

Using the app service deploy task for functions says "Not recommended".
My issue was simple and silly - I had a random zip file in my project, a resource, and that was picked up by the azure function publish task:

```
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'XXXX'
    appType: 'functionApp'
    appName: 'XXXX'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

All I had to do was to fix the package to pick up the right zip file:

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'XXXX'
    appType: 'functionApp'
    appName: 'XXXX'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```